# keeping DRY with piston and backbone.js

Tags: django, backbone.js, django-piston

A major design consideration of backbone.js is bootstrapping. I want to bootstrap my initial view, and then have the page do subsequent calls to the piston API for filtering the result set.

I tried calling piston from the view like so:

```
leaderBoardHandler = Resource(LeaderBoardHandler)
response = leaderBoardHandler(request)

leaderBoardBootStrap = {
    'users' : response.content,
}
```

but piston resources return an HTTP response; and somehow calling the piston api internally from a view feels like I'm making the baby jesus cry.

So this is an architecture question. Should I instead have a common method for my api and view separately? (if so, where?)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what "Piston" is here but sounds like it should be wrapped up by a model. Look at the Model.parse and Backbone.sync that let you talk to custom protocol backends